# Linear gradient and background image on a button

Tags: css

Hey I have one stupid question.

Im trying to create a button which includes both a `.svg` background and a gradient behind it.

It all works nicely but when I add `background-size` to control the size of the image inside the button the gradient starts to repeat itself in a pattern. like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/umbriel/g31nprgz/

Is there a way to make the gradient span the whole height without repeating AND being able to control the image size inside the button?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple background sizes in comma delimited lists, just like background images.

So, your fix is something like this:

```
background-size: 50px, contain;
```

## [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g31nprgz/1/)

Each ordinal corresponds to the same position for the background images, so the first item in the list of `background-size` applies to the first item in the list of `background-image`

Answer (score 1):

`background-size` takes *multiple* values too – so just set the size for your second background image (the gradient) to 100% again,

```
background-size:50px, 100%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g31nprgz/2/